# php includes in .htm files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, include

I've read everything here and tried almost all the suggestions, nothing is helping. 
I've got several static .htm pages that all call common headers & footers via a php include:
        `<?php include('inc_logo_nav.htm');?>`

So I just moved to a new server with all kinds of higher level security and nothing we have tried helps.. the system refuses to allow these include calls unless I change the file extension to .php

On the old server I was using in my .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

But on this new box I had to comment out those lines to get the pages to even come up. The tech guy is stumped too..

> back to suphp & seuexec but no nginx
>   and that didnt help either...

cPanel Server running: CENTOS 6.5 x86_64 vmware – WHM 11.40.

I'm already suffering from loss of traffic, changing all the pages to .php after 20+ years is going to kill the site... Can anyone help here??
Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` this is usually needed on some servers, instead of only `AddType`

Comment: And if on Linux `<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .php .htm
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymlinks` --- there are a number of ways to do this. These are but two; I could go on, yet these are the two most common methods.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to make your .html be executed like it's .php? Because your statement is a bit contradicting "I've got several static .htm pages that all call common headers & footers via a php include". static != php

Comment: Advice for future - run tests on new machines before switching, and probably hire new tech guy, since this is server configuration issue that should be resolved in 5 minutes

Comment: Maybe try `require`?  `include` stops the script while `require` gives a warning

Comment: `include` always parse file as `php` so this is not a misconfiguration. It seems a security restriction

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these in your .htaccess?

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .html .htm
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .html .htm
```

I needed them on a server hosted by 1&1 to cause HTML files to be parsed as PHP.